# What formula is used for the increase in training speed by having multiple barracks

Tags: kingdoms-of-camelot

I was under the impression (apparently mistakenly) that having multiple barracks of a level capable of training a given troop would allow you to spread the training around. For example, if I have a troop who requires a level 6 barracks to train, and my barracks are levels `7 6 5 4`, then it will train twice as fast. If I instead trained a troop who required level 5, it would train 3x as fast since I have 3 barracks to train them at.

However, I experimented with this and it had no effect. I am unable to empirically determine any pattern (or for that matter, even notice a difference) in training speed as a result of having multiple barracks. My attempts to search for such a formula has proved unfruitful.

What is the formula for determining training speed?

(I'm playing Battle for the North if that makes a difference - there wasn't a tag for it, and I'm not experienced enough in the game to know if there's a difference between the two!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, calculate the base training time.

- Supply troops - 30 seconds each
- T1 and supply carts - 90 seconds each
- T2 and supply wagons - 480 seconds each
- T3 - 1200 seconds each

Then calculate your barracks score. The score is 1 for each barracks and .1 for each additional barracks level. So having a 1, 2, 3 and 4 barracks would be 1 + 1.1 + 1.2 + 1.3 = 4.6. If you had 16 level 9 barracks, you'd be looking at 16 * 1.8 = 28.8.

Then simply divide the base training time by the barracks score to get your reduced training time.

So 1000 T3 would take 1,200,000 seconds, with the 16 level 9 barracks, this is 1200000 / 28.8 = 41,667 seconds, or 11.5 hours.

This does not take into account geometry and marshal, which continue to substantially reduce training time.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two things at play here.  Firstly, in order to train troops of a particular level, your highest barracks is what allows you to train that troop (i.e. makes it available in the first place).  Any additional barracks regardless of the level only reduce the training time.  I am trying to work out how much and so far I can only confirm that the biggest boost you get is for having additional barracks at level 1 in the first place.

Levelling them up boosts the training more but it seems to me that it is not as much as building the additional barracks in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I actually figured out the formula, but I forgot about my question and hadn't posted my answer! I shall post it, thanks for reminding me I had this.